# Genexus Ev2 Stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, genexus, rpg

I'm trying to call a stored procedure on my iSeries System (RPG program) but I'm not able ***to activate the corresponding menu*** under "tools"->"`Java` Generator".

The RPG program that I want to call (we'll name it RPG00) has 5 input parameters and 1 output value.

I performed the following operations:

- Create an "external `object`" (type: stored procedure) whose name is "*RPG00*"
- Create a method named "*RPG00*" as well in the external object above and set the "external name" property to "*RPG00*"
- Create a `Web Panel` with a variable &test (type: external object *RPG00*) and call it with the right parameters
- Change the following settings in iSeries datastore configuration:

  - "access technology to set" --> JDBC
  - "list of external stored procedure" --> RPG00

At this point if i try to build the *KB*, it ends up always in error. In the project folder i can't find the "`crtjdccalls.java`" file and the corresponding "class" file that stores the instructions for the stored procedure..

What's going wrong? Any idea? Any suggestion?
The appropriate element in the "Java generator" menu never appears!!

**My Configuration:**

- Gx Ev2 U5
- Environment: Web\Java
- DB: iSeries 6.1

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot set the data store property (JDBC) 'Library list' with the name of the library in which the RPG progrma RPG00 is found.

Check this and make a rebuild all.

Regards, Luis.

Comment: Thanks Luis, but it doesn't work. I opened a ticket to Artech support hoping they'll give me an answer.

Comment: Please share your answer when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Genuxs development team I found a solution!
The problem is related to the way parameters are passed to the stored procedure.

REMEBER:

- You can't use SDT elements as input parameters
- You can't use direct values as input parameters
- **YOU CAN USE ONLY VARIABLES!!!**

E.G.

```
SDT.value1, SDT.value2
&variable1 = SDT.value1
&variable2 = SDT.value2
&RPG00.RPG00(SDT.value1, SDT.value2, ecc) --> ERROR
&RPG00.RPG00(&variable1, XXX, ecc) --> ERROR where XXX is for example an integer value
&RPG00.RPG00(&variable1, &variable2, ecc) --> ONLY VARIABLES WORK FINE!!
```

Hope this help someone else